# Android Toolbar color not being set by colorPrimary

Tags: android

according to the google docs, I should be able to set the color of Toolbar background using colorPrimary in the theme, but it's not working. Here's what I have:

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_purple</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_purple</item>
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_purple</item>

        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/light_purple</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pivot_title_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="toolbar text view" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

I have set my app theme to AppTheme in the manifest: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`
I have setup android support appcompat in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

But my toolbar, is still not colored. 
**I know I can manually set the toolbar background color manually in the layout file**, but shouldn't it get its color from the theme? as you can see the accent colors are working.

[image]

Comment: I think you might want to remove `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` from the `Toolbar` declaration on `activity_main`, and set the background of the toolbar like `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32981192/5164200) is how I solved my problem. Check it out

Comment: What worked for me was to [set the app theme in the manifest file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39341616/3681880).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Toolbar will not get primary color from your theme. You have to set the following xml property of the toolbar

```
android:background="@color/primary"
```

This is my working implementation of toolbar.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: do you think this is a bug or miscommunication in the appcompat documentation?

Comment: I don't think so. You are creating your custom theme. And they have given background property to specify the color. This is not actionbar.

Comment: I chose this as best answer because its the only answer that acknowledged the fact that I already know how to set the background color manually.

Comment: @ch3tanz 
I see that for background you have set @color/primary.. I see that there has been usage of ?attr/colorPrimary.. However on using it I am not able to get color on v21 and above. Any help?

Comment: @Tejas you have to define styles.xml for v21 and above , then you will get color.

Answer (score 6):

**Style and theme are different.**
The style is **local** to the Toolbar view, for example the background color.
The theme is instead **global** to all ui elements inflated in the Toolbar, for example the color of the title and icons.
More info [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/).

With **Material Components Library**:

- the **`android:background`** attribute in the layout:

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  ```
- apply the default style: **`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"`** or customize the style inheriting from it:

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
  ```
- override the default color using the **`android:theme`** attribute:

  ```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
  ```

with:

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">....</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/.....
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

With **design support library**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       style="@style/HeaderBar"/>
```

where:

```
<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Otherwise you can define the background for your `Toolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `android:` prefixed attributes in the theme for android 5+, as the non-prefixed variant is only for the app compat parts for versions < android 5.

So you should have one `values/styles.xml` for pre-android 5 and one `values-v21/styles.xml` for android 5+.

In the v21 styles you define your theme as following:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/light_purple</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_purple</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/dark_purple</item>
</style>
```

As you now define the colorPrimary attribute once simply as `colorPrimary` for pre-Lollipop and once as `android:colorPrimary` for Lollipop devices, you can no longer directly use `?attr/colorPrimary`. Instead, like others here said before, you should define your own style for the toolbar, but for both variations:

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Toolbar">
  <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Toolbar">
  <item name="android:background">?android:attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

And use the style for your toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/Toolbar"
```

Like this the background color and other styles can be set on all versions and is still changeable by the `colorPrimary` that is set in the theme(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background color to toolbar

This worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:gravity="right"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading_news"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: It's preferable to refer to the primary color like this: `android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"`

Comment: So the Toolbar will NOT automatically get the color from the theme?